# How to get User information from JWT cookie in NextJS / ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, next.js

I am learning about Next.JS and React and was wondering if it is possible to get user details from the cookie storing the JWT.

I have managed to set the JWT as the cookie and can log it successfully and have also managed to decode it but can't find anything on how to get username, id, etc from it. Here's what I have so far:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "../components/App.js";
import cookie from "react-cookies";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
 static async getInitialProps() {
  const token = cookie.load("jwt");
  return { token };
 }

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = props.token;
 }

render() {
  const current_user = jwt_decode(this.props.token, { header: true });

return (
  <App>
    <p>Username: {current_user.username}</p>
  </App>
  );
  }
}
```

Ideally, i'd like to be able to set the cookie value to a user variable and extract properties from it, e.g. current_user.username. Unless i've got it completely wrong and have missed out something really important! Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: What's the current behavior?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use this `parseJwt` function to extract the user data:

```js
function parseJwt(token) {
    if (!token) { return; }
    const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    const base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
}

console.log(parseJwt('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'))
```

It will extract the data inside a jwt token and will return an object

Comment: This is perfect if you want a vanilla JS solution.

Comment: is it safe to use window in NextJS (SSR)?

Comment: @Mehmet probably not, but you can use Buffer native in node.js when code runs on the server, just check if the window object exists and if not do `Buffer.from(token.toString(), 'base64').toString('ascii')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `npm` package. Simply run  `npm install jwt-decode` in the `cmd` and use the following code:

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"; 
  
const token = "eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token";
const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
```